# How do i initialize value to the int variables im using the main function with user input from the getData function?

Tags: c++

> In the main function, define four variables of type int, named: first, second, third, and total.
>
> Write a function named getData that asks the user to input three integers and stores them in the variables first, second, and third which are in the main function.
>
> Write a function named computeTotal that computes and returns the total of three integers.
>
> Write a function named printAll that prints all the values in the format shown in the following sample:
>
> 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
>
> Call the other three functions from the main function.
>
> Test it once, with the values 4, 5, and 6.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getData() {
    cout << "Enter 3 Integer Values: ";
    cin >> first >> second >> third;
    return first, second, third;
}

int calcTotal() {
    total = first + second + third;
    return total;
}

int printTotal() {
    cout << total;
}

int main() {
    int first, second, third, total;
    getData();
    calcTotal();
    printTotal();
}
```

Comment: `return first, second, third;` doesn't do what you think it does. And in this example, you don't even need the `return` since the returned value is ignored in `main()`

Comment: Did my answer help you?  If it did, *please* mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically impossible using the code layout you describe.

However!

It is possible using something called pass-by-reference in C++.
By default, when you pass a parameter into a function the value is copied.  But what pass-by-reference does is it passes the variable, not it's value.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
void setToFive(int& x){// the ampersand signifies pass-by-reference
    x = 5; // This change is preserved outside of the function because x is pass-by-reference
}
int main(){
    int x = 200;
    std::cout << "X before = "<<x<<std::endl;
    setToFive(x);
    std::cout << "X after = "<<x<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So this pass-by-reference means that changes to variables in the method are saved outside of the method.

So your code would look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
void getData(int&first, int&second, int&third){
    std::cout<<"Enter 3 Integer Values: ";
    std::cin>>first>>second>>third;
}
int calcTotal(int first, int second, int third){//Pass as parameters, so the method knows what numbers to add
    return first + second + third;
}//calcTotal returns the total
void printTotal(int total){//printTotal doesn't return anything! printTotal only prints stuff, it doesn't have a numeric result to give you
    std::cout<<"Total: "<<total;
}
int main(){
    int first,second,third;
    getData(first,second,third);
    int total=calcTotal(first,second,third);
    printTotal(total);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. NEVER NEVER EVER EVER USE `using namespace std;` in your code.
It causes death, destruction, and annoying answers by people who believe it is a bad thing.

P.P.S.  Seeing the introductory level you're at, I would recommend starting with Python.  Check that out!  It's a lot easier to learn.

Comment: I disagree with the "go learn python" bit =) but fairly good answer

Comment: Lol I upvoted your comment :P.  Thanks for the comment, this is my first serious answer.  Generally speaking, with English difficulties, the sometimes (read:always) hard-to-decipher maze of C++ awfulness and templates and error messages is bad.  Python is simple and there are multilingual tutorials out there.